# splitting a range using xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I have an xml as below

```
<content>
<customer id="250">
<assert  PropertyType="product" PropertyValues="0009~0013" DisplayClass="confirmed"/>
<assert  PropertyType="product" PropertyValues="0001" DisplayClass="confirmed"/>
</customer>

<customer id="100">
<assert  PropertyType="product" PropertyValues="0008|0010~0012" DisplayClass="confirmed"/>
</customer>

<customer id="6000">
<assert  PropertyType="product" PropertyValues="0013|0036|0042|0047" DisplayClass="confirmed"/>
</customer>
</content>
```

I want to got to each PropertyValues attribute which is in assert tag ,should search for 0011 value from  and return a boolean value
I have different operator like ~(range) and | (separator) which actually mean
PropertyValues="0009~0013"--> 0009 to 0013 -->I have sequence 0009 0010 0011 0013
PropertyValues="0008|0010~0012" --> I have 0008 0010 0011 0012
PropertyValues="0013|0036|0042|0047" --> I have 0013 0036 0042 0047

How can I perform this using Xquery
Any suggestions/ ideas would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't clear: what are you trying to do? What is the **exact** expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tokenize` function to split things up and you can use the range operator `to` to "translate" your range syntax with `~` into a sequence, finally you only need to check whether the resulting sequence contains your value:

```
//@PropertyValues 
! 
(. || ': ' || (((tokenize(., '\|') ! (let $tokens := tokenize(., '~')!xs:integer(.) return $tokens[1] to $tokens[2])) ! format-integer(., '0001')) = '0011'))
```

at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hwpi2 outputs

```
0009~0013: true
0001: false
0008|0010~0012: true
0013|0036|0042|0047: false
```